# Replacing numbers in notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a column with a letter and numbers.

```
A1

A2

A12

A123

A1234
```

I want to replace each number with a dot (or spaces)

```
A.

A.

A..

A...

A....
```

I've tried to search A(\d+) but i have no idea how to replace the number of digits found.
Any idea?
Thanks for help

Comment: Do what @MatiuCarr says unless you have some other unmentioned conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace each digit with a dot or space, rather than replacing all digits with a dot or space.

ie. \d, '.' rather than \d+, '.'

```
re.sub('\d','.', "A1234")
'A....'
re.sub('\d','.', "A12")
'A..'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `\G` anchor that matches the position after a previous match, in this way you can replace all digits that follows an `A` with a global replacement:

```
search: (?:\G(?!^)|A)\K[0-9]
replace: .
```